# Haskell couldn't match expected type, Weird behaviour

Tags: function, haskell

I have a module which looks like this:

```
module Network where
import Prelude hiding ((==))
import Sort
import Message

data Pair = Conn Loc Loc | Disconn Loc Loc deriving(Show,Eq)
data NC = EmpNC | Inn Pair NC 

instance Eq NC where
EmpNC == EmpNC = True
(Inn p nc1) == nc2 = (nc_include p nc2) && (nc1 == nc2)
_ == _ = False

nc_include::Pair->NC->Bool
nc_include p EmpNC = False
nc_include p1 (Inn p2 nc) = (p1 == p2) || (nc_include p1 nc)
```

The weird part is that I get *couldn't match expected type NC with actual type Pair* error for the last line where I say (p1 == p2). Meaning that p1 should be NC rather than Pair. I'm out of idea,can you help?
**[Edit]**  The hiding (==) form prelude thing is because I was getting amibiguity error wherever I had "==" operator. I would appreciate if you also suggest a better solution for that as well :D

Comment: Why don't you just `type NC = [Pair]` (though that wouldn't the desired `==` behaviour), or perhaps `newtype NC = NC { getNCPairs :: [Pair] }`?   And what's up with the hidden `Prelude.==`, do you perhaps import a bad `Eq` class?

Comment: that's a requirement to have such constructors for NC, and I don't think this kind of declaration causes the problem, does it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, here is a working version:

```
module Network where

data Loc = Loc deriving (Show, Eq)
data Pair = Conn Loc Loc | Disconn Loc Loc deriving(Show,Eq)
data NC = EmpNC | Inn Pair NC 

instance Eq NC where
   EmpNC       == EmpNC = True
   (Inn p nc1) == nc2   = (nc_include p nc2) && (nc1 == nc2)
   _           == _     = False

nc_include :: Pair -> NC-> Bool
nc_include p  EmpNC = False
nc_include p1 (Inn p2 nc) = (p1 == p2) || (nc_include p1 nc)
```

What's the difference (besides my arbitrarily defining `Loc`)? Mainly formatting.

I suppose what happened is this:

You tried to write an instance of `Eq` for `NC`:

```
instance Eq NC where
EmpNC == EmpNC = True
...
```

and realized the compiler didn't like this, saying it conflicted with `(==)` from the `Prelude`. However, you drew the wrong conclusions from this, hiding `Prelude.(==)` and going on. Now the compiler didn't complain, but it parsed what you did like this:

```
instance Eq NC where -- make NC an instance of Eq with only default definitions

EmpNC == EmpNC = True -- define a new function (==) of type (NC -> NC -> Bool)
...
```

That's why now you can't apply `(==)` to `Pair`s, because it's type is `(NC -> NC -> Bool)`, hence the compiler tells you that it would have expected an `NC` instead of a `Pair`.

Now, the core of the matter is that instance definitions follow whitespace formatting rules, so you must leave at least one whitespace column before the functions in your `instance` definition:

```
instance Eq NC where 
 EmpNC == ...
```

works, while

```
instance Eq NC where 
EmpNC == ...
```

doesn't.

The same is true for some other things like `class`, `do`, `case` etc.

Comment: Wow! That would make me a life time to realize! very helpful.